# Why does jQuery click event only work once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying make speed units toggle when clicking. However, this only works once. I have run out of things to try. I also tried `.click()`, `.live()`, `.toggle()` (which only made it disappear and reappear), etc.

HTML:

```
<li id="wind">Wind speed</br>
   <p class='windSpeedKm'></p>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
var click = true;

$('#wind').on('click', function() {
  if (click = false) {
    $('#wind').html(function() {
      $(this).html("Wind speed<br>" + windKm);
      click = true;
    });
  } else if (click = true) {
    $('#wind').html(function() {
      $(this).html("Wind speed<br>" + windMi);
      click = false;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Note, you are assigning `click` as `true` at `else if (click = true)`

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Yes like what the other said. Also you could write one event and just pass back either windMi/wind. click can just be set to the opposite after the event call by using click = !click

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but this will **save you so much time** it is unbelievable. It has an auto convert function built in so you don't have to manually update both numbers.  It doesn't replace unnecessary to replace html.

```
<li id="wind">Wind speed</br>
    <p class='windSpeedKm' km="500">500</p>
</li>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function toMiles(km) {
        return parseFloat(km) * 0.62137;
    }

    $('#wind').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("km"));
        windSpeedKm = $(this).find(".windSpeedKm");
        km = windSpeedKm.attr("km");
        if (km === windSpeedKm.html()) {
            windSpeedKm.html(toMiles(km));
        } else {
            windSpeedKm.html(km);
        }       
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax issues with the code:

```
var click = true;

$('#wind').on('click', function() {
  if (click) {
    $(this).html("Wind speed<br>" + windKm):
     click = true;
  } else {
    $(this).html("Wind speed<br>" + windMi);
     click = false;
  }
});
```

**Note**: there isn't any need to set `click = true` or `click = false` in your example as falling into the if statement by checking the `click` assignment value, this will already be true! You would only do this if you wanted to toggle the boolean to false after confirming it was true.

Answer (score 0):

`click = true` should be `click == true;`